subsetting in R gives empty data.frame
we found a surprising result from basic code in R. We search for answers online but found nothing.
Does anyone knows the reason of this result?
the following code generates a fake data.frame
z2 <- data.frame(a=rep(1:120,100), b=rep(rep(c(0,1),each=120),50), c=rep(rep(c(0,1),each=240),25), d=rep(rep(seq(.1,2.5,.1),each=120),4)
we want the subset of z2 having d==1.5, but the result is an empty data.frame.
subset(z2,d==1.5)
[1] a b c d
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
however, the value 1.5 is present in the dataframe
z2[7750,]
  a b c   d

7750 70 0 0 1.5
but simple functions do not work:
table(z2$d==1.5)
FALSE
12000
can anyone say what the h*** has happened ? please help, my head has exploded XD
G.M.

This is an issue common to most all programming languages - floating point (non-integer) numbers can't be stored exactly in binary, so using an exact equality check may not work. The linked FAQ has much more information and several suggested solutions. A simple one is to use a tolerance, something like subset(z2, abs(d - 1.5) < 1e-6)

If you use library(dplyr), another option is the near function,subset(z2, near(d, 1.5))
